# Adding a simple new account in the django admin doesn’t ask for the correct fields

Tags: python, django

I’m new to django and am sure this is probably a quick spot for most. I essentially want to:

- Change the default User model to use an email (and password) to log in (instead of username)
- Add extra fields to the default User model

I’ve followed a video tutorial that resulted in me writing this code:

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),  # converts chars to lowercase
            password=password,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):  # password=None?
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email",
                              max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    # username field unwanted - only added to get rid of fielderror "Unknown field(s) (username) specified for Account. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class AccountAdmin."
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True)
    # @todo: add more new fields

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # so users use email to log in
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):  # add -> str: type?
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from accounts.models import Account

class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'date_joined', 'is_staff', 'is_admin')
    search_fields = ('email', 'date_joined')
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login')  # make fields immutable
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()
    ordering = ()

admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

My questions are as follows:

1. When using the createsuperuser command, why does it only require me to type in a password once? (I thought it should ask again to confirm; it just asks for email and password fields once)
2. When clicking on ‘add account’ in django admin, why doesn’t it ask for an email and password? (It asks for an un-required username and required password (and 2nd password-retype)
3. The point of these classes is to just try to user the default User model (instead of creating my own Account class for example) and edit it to rid the username field and add other new fields. Am I overcomplicating the solution here and, instead, should I just create a new class that simply extends the User model like the example below?

```
class Account(User):
     new_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
     objects = UserManager()
```

Is this way just simpler and better for me: https://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

When clicking ‘add account’ in the django admin, does it try to create a new super user, or just a new instance of the MyAccountManager, Account or AccountAdmin class?

Thanks for helping a beginner out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The application does what you have told it to do, and as per your MyAccountManager class you have to enter the password only once.
2. I would think that the problem occurs in the admin.py bit. Your AccountAdmin inherits from UserAdmin class, which aims at serving the Django User model. In order to work with your custom user model, use ModelAdmin.

   from django.contrib import admin
   from accounts.models import Account

   ```
    class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('email', 'date_joined', 'is_staff', 'is_admin')
        search_fields = ('email', 'date_joined')
        readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login')  # make fields immutable
        filter_horizontal = ()
        list_filter = ()
        fieldsets = ()
        ordering = ()

    admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
   ```
3. I would say the Django User model will not work for you, because you need to set a unique email field, get rid of the username, and use email when logging the user in. As per Django documentation in this situation you need to implement a custom user model.